# Why my GPS does not give me the exact location?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm trying to get the exact longitude and latitude of a android device. The problem is that when setting data in google maps, I realize that the position is not correct. I think the device is getting any previously saved position

```
                LocationManager locationManager;
                String svcName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
                locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(svcName);

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                updateWithNewLocation(location);

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);

                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.i("lon", longitude+"" );
                    Log.i("lat", latitude+"");
                }else{
                    Log.i("Null", "Es nulo");
                }
```

**LocationListener**

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,int status,Bundle extras){}
};
```

**xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

How can I fix it?? I need the current position of teh devices

Comment: your position can vary depending on if you are inside/outside, position of GPS satellites and even the device itself

Comment: @MichaelTodd At least a mile

Comment: @tyczj But a mile is a distance I can not use. I need the code to be more demanding

Comment: @zhelon output the timestamp, then you can calculate the time diference to current time, if it is less than some seconds, it is a current but wrong position. If the time is very old, then it is the last valid position.

Comment: there is no magic you can do that will give you better coordinates when you need it. if you are not getting good coordinates then its either your device or you dont have a good lock on a satellite. you should also be using google play services location API and not the old one

Comment: @AlexWien I was doing a lot of testing and I'm sure the gps returns a saved position

Comment: Of course! you request a saved one! getLastKnownLocation() delivers t he last known! It might be from yetserday and in the mean time you had not GPS receievment possible. Use location only from onLocationChanged() or do the time differnce check I described in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
  Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

delivers the last know, even if that location is from yesterday.

Remove the line, cnage the code appropriate, and wait till you get an location event in `onLocationChanged()`.

- Further you may check: the timestamp of the location: caluclate the difference to current time and you know if it is a recent  location.
- Further check location getHoricontalAccuracy() (or named similar) if it is above 40m ignore the location.